# Can a character affected by the Death Curse choose to automatically undo it after the release of Season 7 Tier 3 material?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, dnd-adventurers-league, tomb-of-annihilation

I have a Tier 2 character currently affected by the Death Curse after playing a Season 7 module, and I want to get rid of  that curse as soon as possible (but I haven't started playing the Tomb of Annihilation Hardcover yet, so ending the Death Curse by completing its story with my character would most likely take a very long time).

I have, however, read information about Season 7 Tier 3 material being able to make you automatically end the Death Curse on your characters. So, as I want to be sure that I understood properly, is the following statement accurate ?

"Once Season 7 Tier 3 material is released (supposedly in January 2018, so should be in a few weeks after this question is posted), I can simply choose to end the Death Curse on any of my Tier 1/2 characters currently affected by it - this permanently prevents me from playing Season 7 Tier 1/2 material (Tomb of Annihilation + DDAL07-X) with these characters, but not other seasons' Tier 1/2 material"